# What is the C# equavilent of C++ :: (non-static)

Tags: c#, c++, operator-keyword

I've been working with C++ for a while now, and I picked up C# a few weeks ago. When writing initialisers, I have found that I do not know a way to use the :: operator.

In C++, it looks like:

```
class something{
    bool a;
    void doSg();
}
void doSg(){
    something::a = true;
}
int main()
{
    something mySg;
    mySg.doSg();
}
```

So, I tried to recreate the `void doSg()` function in C#: a method that modifies that class object's data that it's been called for.
In the following code:

```
class something
{
    bool a;
    public void func()
    {
        this.a = true;
    }
}
class source
{
    something mySg;
    mySg.func();
}
```

is `this.a = true` valid, or should I make:

```
class something
{
    bool a;
    public myclass func(myclass item)
    {
        item.a = true;
        return item;
    }
}
class source
{
    something mySg;
    mySg = func(mySg);
}
```

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: `this` is a pointer in c++, and is implicit anyway.

Comment: @KvB It is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve. And I do not see the ::operator in your question.

Comment: It looks a little like you didn't post the real code

Comment: @David Heffernan, yes, this is an example I put up right now. I don't have trouble with anything else, so I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: It's just that when you don't post real code, we can't really know what you mean.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I edited the question again, hopefully it's clear now.

Comment: Your edit isn't much better. Fake code is no use.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could tell me what exactly is wrong with it. I try not to put the unnecessary part of the code that doesn't relate to the question.
Anyway, I realised I made some mistakes in the code. Edited that one as well.

Comment: @KvB what you've posted does not look like valid C++ code... It makes it very harder what you want to achieve. Since you've accepted an answer you know what you tried to ask now - please consider either updating the question to math the answer or simply deleting if you don't care.

Comment: I'm just doing an epic facepalm here for not realising the insane "code" I've made. Edited. Thanks. I'm not in a productive mood by any means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var here is a keyword so it probably would not work like you are using it. You can do something like this:

```
class something {
    bool myBool; 

    public void func()
    {
        this.myBool= true;
        myBool= true;  //or you can just leave this "this" off
    } 
}
```

When calling *something.func()* it will set myBool to true.

"this" just refers to the class(or struct) itself and does not need to be used that often.  You just need it in the event that there are duplicate names like this...

```
class something {
    bool myBool; 

    public void func(bool myBool)
    {
        myBool= myBool; //would not do anything
        this.myBool= myBool;  //force class myBool
    } 
}
```

As for return,  you would need it for that second example you have listed but the var needs to be changed or removed.

```
class something
{
public Myclass func(myclass item)
    {
        Myclass item = new myClass(); // first create a class
        return item; //since myclass in in the header, we need to return a myclass
    }
}
```

I updated the myClass to MyClass because classes should start with a captial but this is not required. I hope this helps some. C# is different then C++ when it comes to all the details.

Comment: As it was an example, I didn't test it in VS so I didn't know about the "var" keyword. I did not do it on purpose. The description you've given is decent, though. Thanks!